# HTML Agility Pack not matching xpath where attribute name starts-with

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, .net-7.0

I am trying to select all HTML nodes where the node contains an attribute with a name starting with 'on'.

This is what I have for the XPath:

```
//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'on')]]
```

I am getting null back when calling `SelectNodes` with the above xpath and html `<div onclick="alert('test');"></div>`.

```cs
var document = new HtmlDocument();

document.LoadHtml("<div onclick=\"alert('test');\"></div>");

var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'on')]]");
```

I have tested the XPath on a couple of XPath testing sites (https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#before-output and http://xpather.com/) and they all return the div node. Do xpath functions not work with HTML Agility Pack? Do I need to do something different for the HTML Agility Pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work if you use the `local-name()` function instead. I think it is a bug in HtmlAgilityPack. If you look at the implementation of `HtmlNodeNavigator.LocalName` [here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/7c35d8f8f698a76a57dafe22d3d23b65b3815cd3/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNodeNavigator.cs#L321), it accounts for `_attIndex` being set and returns the name of the corresponding attribute. However, the implementation of `HtmlNodeNavigator.Name` that follows [here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/7c35d8f8f698a76a57dafe22d3d23b65b3815cd3/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNodeNavigator.cs#L339) does not account at all for `_attIndex`. So in your case, even though the `HtmlNodeNavigator` may currently be pointing to the attribute itself via `_attIndex`, the call to the `.Name` property erroneously returns `div` instead of `onclick`.

I would [file an issue in their GitHub repo](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/issues/new).